# Inheritance with annotation in Java8

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I know annotation can neither be inherited nor subclass/s contain parent level annotation. But, I have a simple scenario. Suppose, I have N number of classes like A,B,C,D......N. 

A is the super class and B,C,D....N are the children i.e. subclass of A.So, if I need inheritence for these these classes I need to do it in following way:

```
class B extends A {
     //code
}

class C extends A {
     //code
}
......
class N extends A {
     //code
}
```

So I need to manually extends class A for N number of times. 
Now, my question is couldn't I create a **@ParentIsClassA** like annotation, by which child level classes would automatically extend class A?

Sample code which I want to implement is below:

```
@ParentIsClassA
class B {
    //code
}

@ParentIsClassA
class N {
    //code
}
```

Comment: I do not know if it is possible, but it certainly seems likie a bad idea, it makes the code less obvious and if you are aiming for less typing, your desired version is actually longer.

Answer (score 3):

Annotations typically can't modify a class's compilation in Java. (Lombok uses special and fragile compiler hooks; Groovy ASTs can do what you're talking about.)

That said, *why*? You still have to insert that annotation just like the `extends` clause, and then you have issues like IDEs not understanding the relationships. Just use normal inheritance and don't confuse your tools and other programmers.

You might also be interested in [the `@Inherited` meta-annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion....can you please share some code sample of @Inherited by which I can do this?